# Stripe symfony subscription user

Tags: stripe-payments, symfony5

I'm new to stripe, I managed to make the payment via the doc but I can't link my user to the subscription, for example I would like that when the payment is made, in my user entity I would like whether the user is put in premium or when the subscription is cancelled, whether the user is not in premium.
In my user entity I put a "premium" boolean field

Can you help me please?

```
#[Route('/abonnement/panier/2/checkout', name: 'aboCheck')]
public function stripe2(Request $request): Response
{
    if (!$this->getUser()) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('public');
    }

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test....');

    $priceId = 'price.....';
    if (!$priceId) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Bad plan id!');
    }
    $username = $this->getUser()->getUsername();
    $email = $this->getUser()->getEmail();
    $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
        'success_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/abonnement/panier/2/order/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        'cancel_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/abonnement/panier/2',
        'mode' => 'subscription',
        'line_items' => [[
            'price' => $priceId,
            // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
            'quantity' => 1,
        ]],
        'client_reference_id' => $username,
        'customer_email' => $email,
        'metadata' => [
            'username' => $username
        ]
    ]);
    return $this->redirect($session->url);
}

#[Route('/webhook', name: 'webhook')]
public function handle(ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
{
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk....');

    $endpoint_secret = 'whsec.....';

    $payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
    $event = null;

    try {
        $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
            $payload,
            $sig_header,
            $endpoint_secret
        );
    } catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
        // Invalid payload
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
        // Invalid signature
        http_response_code(400);
        exit();
    }
    $user = $this->getUser();
    // Handle the event
    switch ($event->type) {
        case 'customer.subscription.trial_will_end':
            $subscription = $event->data->object;
            print_r($subscription); // contains a \Stripe\Subscription
            // Then define and call a method to handle the trial ending.
            // handleTrialWillEnd($subscription);
            break;
        case 'customer.subscription.created':
            $subscription = $event->data->object;
            print_r($subscription); // contains a \Stripe\Subscription
            // Then define and call a method to handle the subscription being created.
            // handleSubscriptionCreated($subscription);
            break;
        case 'customer.subscription.deleted':
            $subscription = $event->data->object;
            print_r($subscription); // contains a \Stripe\Subscription
            // Then define and call a method to handle the subscription being deleted.
            // handleSubscriptionDeleted($subscription);
            break;
        case 'customer.subscription.updated':
            $subscription = $event->data->object;
            print_r($subscription); // contains a \Stripe\Subscription
            // Then define and call a method to handle the subscription being updated.
            // handleSubscriptionUpdated($subscription);
            break;
        default:
            // Unexpected event type
            error_log('Received unknown event type');
    }



    return new Response(Response::HTTP_OK);
}
#[Route('/abonnement/panier/2/order/success', name: 'success')]
public function successStripe(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, Request $request): Response
{
    if (!$this->getUser()) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('public');
    }
    $priceId = 'price......';
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk......');

    // Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
    $myuser = $this->getUser();

    $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve($request->get('session_id'));
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($session->customer);
    if (($session->status == 'complete') & ($customer->email == $myuser->getEmail())) {

        $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
        $myuser->setProfileId($customer->id);
        $myuser->setPremium(true);
        $entityManager->flush();
    } else {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('aboStripe');
    }

    return $this->render('stripe/success.html.twig', [
        'customer' => $customer
    ]);
}
#[Route('/customer-portal', name: 'customer-portal')]
public function portal(): Response
{
    // Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test.....');

    // This is the URL to which the user will be redirected after they have
    // finished managing their billing in the portal.
    $myuser = $this->getUser();
    $stripe_customer_id = $myuser->getProfileId();

    $session = \Stripe\BillingPortal\Session::create([
        'customer' => $stripe_customer_id,
        'return_url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/abonnement/panier/2',
    ]);
    return $this->redirect($session->url);
}
```

Comment: You could use the Checkout Session [`client_reference_id`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-client_reference_id) or [`metadata`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-metadata) to store information about your user. Then listen to the [`checkout.session.completed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) webhook event to know when the first payment is made, and you can use the `client_reference_id` or `metadata` in the event payload to update the user on your end.

Comment: can you show me an example please?

Comment: You can learn more about Checkout Sessions and webhooks here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders

Comment: thanks, I followed the doc you sent me, I managed to do my requests after 'checkout.session.completed' but I can't do the opposite for 'customer.subscription.deleted'

Comment: For `customer.subscription.deleted`, you will get a Subscription in the event payload (and it doesn't have the metadata set on the Checkout Session). So one option is to retrieve the Checkout Session with the Subscription ID using [this endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list). The other option is when you receive the event `checkout.session.completed` to update the subscription to include the metadata you need.